# JQuery DataTables Plugin not showing data ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a index action that loads all my products from the database. I have verified that there are products being pulled and it sends them to the view.

The only issue is when the view loads it says there are no data entries in the table?

**Controller**

```
public class InventoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Product> _productContext;
    public InventoryController(IRepository<Product> productContext)
    {
        _productContext = productContext;
    }
    // GET: Inventory
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Product> Products = _productContext.Collection().ToList();
        return View(Products);
    }
}
```

**View With script**

```
@model IEnumerable<SuperStockpile.Core.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inventory";
}

<h2>Inventory</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New Product","Create","Inventory",null,new {@class = "btn btn-primary"})
</p>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="products">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UPC)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SKU)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cost)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiscountPercent)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCode)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedAt)</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#products').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong. The data table shows up in the view as it is supposed to. It is as if the data is not making it to my view?

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I would start by changing `@model IEnumerable<SuperStockpile.Core.Models.Product>` to `@model List<SuperStockpile.Core.Models.Product>`. Iterating over an IEnumerable breaks in weird ways for me sometimes.

Comment: When I did that I lost access to all my product properties and the web page threw an error.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Are you `@using System.Collections.Generic`? You're returning a `List<>` to the view, so naturally the view should have `@model List<>` at the top. By returning a `List<>` to the view only to interpret it as `@model IEnumerable<>` in the view you're losing some capabilities of the `List` class

Comment: Yes I am using that. And yeah I put the @model List<> at the top instead and it said the model has no property called UPC.

Comment: Because this `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UPC)` is trying to access property UPC on the `List` object, not on the items in the `List`. You need to put all the `@Html.DisplayNameFor` inside a foreach loop, and in that foreach loop do `foreach (var m in Model) ` with `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => m.UPC)`

Comment: That error has nothing to do with changing it to a `List` by the way. You're getting that error because your razor code is not correct

Comment: I'll make an answer to show you what I mean

Comment: @Selthien! I think you are only rendering the table header `<thead>` and there is no datarows rendered under `<tbody>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That should work:

```
@model IEnumerable<SuperStockpile.Core.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inventory";
}

<h2>Inventory</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New Product","Create","Inventory",null,new {@class = "btn btn-primary"})
</p>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="products">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UPC)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SKU)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cost)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiscountPercent)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCode)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedAt)</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 @foreach (var m in @model) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@m.UPC</td>
            <td>@m.SKU</td>
            <td>@m.Cost</td>
            <td>@m.DiscountPercent</td>
            <td>@m.ItemCode</td>
            <td>@m.CreatedAt</td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#products').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Rather than a raw code dump, you should explain exactly what you did to resolve the issue.